# Bootstrap 3: How are form-groups meant to be used inside of columns?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3, and I have a fairly standard page layout: one wide column on the left (`.col-md-8`), containing plain text, and one narrower column on the right (`.col-md-4`), containing a form.

Each of the form fields, in turn, is wrapped in a `.form-group`.

In [my first attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/zekukdfv/2/), the `.form-groups` were spilling over the left and right edges of the containing column. (Make sure the JSFiddle preview frame is at least as wide as Bootstrap's sm breakpoint.) I've added a pink background div to show the box that the `.form-groups` *should* be staying within.

In [my second attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/fr6p90ar/1/), I added a `.container` inside of the `.col-md-4`, then wrapped each `.form-group` inside of a `.row` *and* a `.col-md-4`.

This does the trick, but...is this the correct and preferred way? It seems like an awful lot of extra, boilerplate markup to achieve something that should just kinda happen naturally.

The Bootstrap docs are pretty good, but they gloss over some of the "big picture" stuff like this. Maybe this stuff is obvious to folks who are already experienced with responsive CSS, but it can be pretty confusing for a beginner like me.

Here's the code from my first attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
</script>
<head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>Broken version</h1>
    <h2>Don't forget to expand the width of this preview window. Otherwise you'll just see Boostrap's xs (vertically stacked) layout.</h2>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">

            <div style="background-color: orange;">
                <p>This column will be filled with text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- .col-md-8 -->

        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div style="background-color: pink;">

                <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">                    
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email">                    
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

                </form>

            </div> <!-- pink background div -->

        </div> <!-- .col-md-4 -->

    </div> <!-- .row -->

</div> <!-- .container -->

</body>

</html>
```

And here's the code from my second, possibly corrected attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>Corrected (?) version</h1>
    <h2>Don't forget to expand the width of this preview window. Otherwise you'll just see Boostrap's xs (vertically stacked) layout.</h2>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">

            <div style="background-color: orange;">
                <p>This column will be filled with text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- .col-md-8 -->

        <div class="col-md-4">

            <div style="background-color: pink;">

                <div class="container">

                    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">                    
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email">                    
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

                    </form>

                </div> <!-- .container -->

            </div> <!-- .pink background div -->

        </div> <!-- .col-md-4 -->

    </div> <!-- .row -->

</div> <!-- .container -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are not required to use .form-horizontal so don't because this is not a .form-horizontal situation. Look at the docs for .form-horizontal examples, this is not where you would use that class. Use no class on your form and see that you don't need the .container to zero out the negative margin on the .form-group

Comment: You can use .form-group instead of .row if you want some bottom margin.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Both previous answers lack reading the Bootstrap docs.*

You are not required to use `.form-horizontal` so don't because this is not a `.form-horizontal` situation. Look at the docs for `.form-horizontal` examples, this is not where you would use that class. Use no class on your form then you don't need the .container to zero out the negative margin on the `.form-group`.

### http://jsfiddle.net/fr6p90ar/6/

Same as yours without `.form-horizontal` and with without nested .container (read the docs).

also this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
```

is like putting a column class on a .row, it will mess things up significantly.

Just use:

```
<div class="form-group">
```

Comment: your version still shows the text-inputs sticking out over the pink area if you scale the window just right ...

Comment: Yes, it is the wrong link: http://jsfiddle.net/fr6p90ar/6/ His example had the set up very wrong.

Comment: Bah; the extraneous `.form-horizontal` was my entire problem. Can't believe I missed that. It wasn't a matter of not having read the docs; it was just a dumb mistake that I failed to notice. Sorry; I've been working some very long hours lately.

Regarding the `.form-group.col-md-4` issue: thanks for the clarification, but again, I *have* read the docs. I'm glad that this point is obvious to you from the docs, but it isn't for me - I'm learning Bootstrap and responsive design for the first time under extreme time pressure.

Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: Everyone makes them but you make fewer when you realize that 99.99% of problems are simple errors AND you learn to indent, comment, and keep really clean code. Stitch in time saves nine and all that. col-X-4 is 33.333% wherever it goes and it always adds gutter. You don't need any column classes when something is full width, nested inside somewhere or not. Even col-X-12 is rarely needed.

Answer (score 1):

This should help (from the boostrap doc: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

> Use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of
>   form controls in a horizontal layout by adding .form-horizontal to the
>   form. Doing so changes .form-groups to behave as grid rows, so no need
>   for .row.

so considering this you can clean up your html quite a bit - and you can also remove the container. Here's a fiddle to a little bit cleaner version of your form: http://jsfiddle.net/fr6p90ar/2/

```
<div class="col-md-4"  style="background-color: pink;">

                    <form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name"/>                    

                        </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                                <input class="text form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email"/>                    
                            </div>


                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

                    </form>

        </div> <!-- .col-md-4 -->
```

Comment: thanks for the deeplink - let me edit my post to reflect for those who don't read the comments

Comment: Please read the docs, this is a stacked form, there is no class and no need for .container, including a class on the form itself.

Comment: He really just needs to remove the class on the form and not use nested .container and nested .row

Comment: your example still leaves the class "form-horizontal" on the form, this is a vertical form.

Comment: listen, i know you know bootstrap well and i am ok with that. as far as i know there is no such thing as a "form-vertical" - there is form-inline. if you'd like to argue that just because the form is not taking up a full 12-cols and is nested - and that doesn't make it a horizontal form then i choose to disagree. i know how to read and i don't see a definition in the docs that says: form-horizontal must not be wrapped in parent cols. so - instead of throwing rocks and over and over editing your answer just accept that others can solve problems too.

Comment: My answer was edited because there was more bizarre use of Bootstrap than I realized on his fiddle and I didn't save it after I fixed it. There is no need for any class at all in a stacked form form-horizontal is when you use the grid inside to separate the label from the form-controls in two columns, like an old fashioned table format. I'm not throwing rocks over and over. Others who are not really that familiar with Bootstrap answer incorrectly all the time and I can't monitor them. It's not helpful to help others if you are not actually correct.

Comment: thanks for the downvote @christina ;) - breathe. it's ok. maybe your answer will get accepted and you can sleep better - would you want me to downvote you in return or can we move on?

Comment: I voted down 2 times this year. If you correct it, it will go up. Helping other people here should actually help them.